# How to stream a multilanguage video in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, video-streaming, multilingual

I would like to stream videos from AWS (Amazon Web Service) to Android.
The video must be multilanguage.
What service can I use in AWS?
Possibly I would like to stream only the chosen language.
Is mp4 the right choice?
Thanks

Comment: Checkout https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/using-amazon-cloudfront-for-video-streaming/

Comment: Thank you Haresh Kumar. I was looking for more detailed information on the streaming of multilanguage mp4, and I couldn't find them in the blogs, even if it contained a lot of interesting info.